# Read file contents from VirtualFile - intellij plugin development

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-plugin

How can I read file contents from a `virtual file`. I am currently using this way

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(virtualFile.getInputStream()));
            String currentLine;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(currentLine);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
```

However am getting some garbled string appended when I print the `stringbuilder`.

Answer (score 7):

Some common ways of reading VirtualFile contents are:

- file.contentsToByteArray()
- LoadTextUtil.loadText(file)
- FileDocumentManager.getInstance().getDocument(file).get*CharSequence()

Answer (score 3):

You can use VfsUtil.loadText(virtualFile);

Also, to make sure that the file is updated you can use virtualFile.refresh(false, false);

[here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/virtual_file.html) you can find some more useful information.